# Creating a dynamically-allocated array of std::vectors

Tags: c++

To create a dynamically-allocated array, I use:

```
int *x = new int[100];
```

This creates an array of 100 `int` elements.

However, if I use:

```
std::vector<int> *x = new vector<int>(100);
```

This also creates an array of 100 `int` elements. But why does it not create an array of 100 `vector<int>` elements? And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You have used `()` instead of `[]`. I have added an answer which shows how to dynamically allocate an array of vectors, although I am not sure if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create an 100 vectors each containing 100 integers, just use multiple (nested) vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > x(100, std::vector<int>(100));
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to achieve what you want you need to do:

```
std::vector<int> *x = new vector<int>[100];
```

This will dynamically allocate array of 100 vectors, each vector will be default-constructed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the variable as a vector of vectors, rather than a vector of integers.

```
std::vector<vector<int>> *x = new vector<vector<int>>(100);
```